# Bridegroom's Father Name on Marriage Contract

Tags: nikah

As-salamalaykum,

I am a revert and my father is a non Muslim.

I am getting married in next couple of Weeks In Sha Allah.

The Qazi who shall conduct the marriage is not ready to write or say my non Muslim father's name with my name. E.g Ayaan ibn Santosh Saini

He say he will change my father's name on Marriage contract(Nikahnama) e.g Ayaan ibn Bilal Kabeer.

Is there a Islamic ruling on this to not use non muslim father's Name during Marriage.

Note my father is not going to come to witness this marriage. Bilal is my Friend.

Comment: This needs some more input. For what purpose will your father's name appear in the contract?

Comment: Father name comes in contract when writing Bridegroom name .e.g Ayaan ibn Santosh Saini.

Comment: And what is this qazi's evidence or reason to refuse to write your father's name? My first question has the background that a non-Muslim cannot be waly for a Muslim.

Comment: My father is not coming for witnessing the marriage hence he is not acting as wali. Its just Qazi is saying that he cannot write my name Ayaan ibn Santosh Saini as my father is non Muslim

Comment: There's no acceptable reason for this refusal. A non-Muslim can't be a guardian for a Muslim lady this would be the only acceptable reason to refuse him, or if your father's name would include something that might refer to shirk. But this is something I can't judge as I don't know the meaning of your name.